# Drag and drop functionality in React returns erros

Tags: reactjs, drag-and-drop

I wrote a program for `Drag and Drop files` feature.
**Code:**

```
import React from 'react';
import { Nav, Navbar, Container, Jumbotron } from 'react-bootstrap';
import styled from 'styled-components';

const Styles = styled.div`    
    .navbar { 
        background-color: #fff; 
        border-bottom: 1px solid #4AA69D;
    }
    a, .navbar-nav, .navbar-light .nav-link {
        color: #000;
        &:hover { 
            color: #000; 
        }
    }
    .navbar-brand {
        font-size: 1.4em;
        color: #000;
        display: flex;
        align-items: center;
        text-transform: uppercase;
        letter-spacing: 5px;
        &:hover { 
            color: #000; 
        }
    }
    .imgPos {
        margin-right: 4%;
    }
    .profilediv {
        background: #fff;
        border-radius: 50%;
        border: 1px solid #4AA69D;
        width: 50px;
        height: 50px;
    }
    .dragdropContainer {
        margin-top: 2%;
    }
    .jumbotronSurvey {
        text-align: center;
    }
`;

const Shop = props => {
    // const { data, dispatch } = props;
    const handleDragEnter = e => {
        e.preventDefault();
        e.stopPropagation();
        dispatch({ type: 'SET_DROP_DEPTH', dropDepth: data.dropDepth + 1 });
    };
    const handleDragLeave = e => {
        e.preventDefault();
        e.stopPropagation();
        dispatch({ type: 'SET_DROP_DEPTH', dropDepth: data.dropDepth - 1 });
        if (data.dropDepth > 0) return
        dispatch({ type: 'SET_IN_DROP_ZONE', inDropZone: false })
    };
    const handleDragOver = e => {
        e.preventDefault();
        e.stopPropagation();
    };
    const handleDrop = e => {
        e.preventDefault();
        e.stopPropagation();
    };
    const reducer = (state, action) => {
        switch (action.type) {
            case 'SET_DROP_DEPTH':
                return { ...state, dropDepth: action.dropDepth }
            case 'SET_IN_DROP_ZONE':
                return { ...state, inDropZone: action.inDropZone };
            case 'ADD_FILE_TO_LIST':
                return { ...state, fileList: state.fileList.concat(action.files) };
            default:
                return state;
        }
    };
    const [data, dispatch] = React.useReducer(
        reducer, { dropDepth: 0, inDropZone: false, fileList: [] }
    )
    return(
        <Styles>
            <Navbar expand="lg">
                <Navbar.Brand href="/">
                <img
                    alt=""
                    src="/image.png"
                    width="30"
                    height="30"
                    className="d-inline-block align-top imgPos"
                    />{' '}
                    SurveyChamp
                </Navbar.Brand>
                <Nav className="ml-auto">
                    <div className="profilediv">
                        <span>
                            {/* ToBeAddedLater */}
                        </span>
                    </div>
                </Nav>
            </Navbar>
            <Container fluid className="dragdropContainer">
                <Jumbotron className="jumbotronSurvey"
                        onDrop={e => handleDrop(e)}
                        onDragOver={e => handleDragOver(e)}
                        onDragEnter={e => handleDragEnter(e)}
                        onDragLeave={e => handleDragLeave(e)}
                        data={data} dispatch={dispatch}
                    >
                    <h5>
                        Drag and drop a JSON file to create a survey
                    </h5>
                </Jumbotron>
            </Container>
        </Styles>
    );
};

export default Shop;
```

Running this code returns this error.

> Invalid value for prop `dispatch` on  tag. Either remove it from the element, or pass a string or number value to keep it in the DOM.

I've declared both `data` and `dispatch`. However `Drag and drop` functionality doesn't work. What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

Fixed it!!
I created a component for DragAndDrop feature. Here is modified code:
**DragnDrop:**

```
import React from 'react';
import { Jumbotron } from 'react-bootstrap';

const DragnDrop = props => { 
    const { data, dispatch } = props;

    const handleDragEnter = e => {
        e.preventDefault();
        e.stopPropagation();

        dispatch({ type: 'SET_DROP_DEPTH', dropDepth: data.dropDepth + 1 });
    };

    const handleDragLeave = e => {
        e.preventDefault();
        e.stopPropagation();

        dispatch({ type: 'SET_DROP_DEPTH', dropDepth: data.dropDepth - 1 });
        if (data.dropDepth > 0) return
        dispatch({ type: 'SET_IN_DROP_ZONE', inDropZone: false })
    };

    const handleDragOver = e => {
        e.preventDefault();
        e.stopPropagation();

        e.dataTransfer.dropEffect = 'copy';
        dispatch({ type: 'SET_IN_DROP_ZONE', inDropZone: true });
    };

    const handleDrop = e => {
        e.preventDefault();
        e.stopPropagation();

        let files = [...e.dataTransfer.files];

        if (files && files.length > 0) {
        const existingFiles = data.fileList.map(f => f.name)
        files = files.filter(f => !existingFiles.includes(f.name))

        dispatch({ type: 'ADD_FILE_TO_LIST', files });
        dispatch({ type: 'SET_DROP_DEPTH', dropDepth: 0 });
        dispatch({ type: 'SET_IN_DROP_ZONE', inDropZone: false });
        }
    };
    return (
        <Jumbotron 
            className={data.inDropZone ? 'drag-drop-zone inside-drag-area' : 'drag-drop-zone'}
            onDrop={e => handleDrop(e)}
            onDragOver={e => handleDragOver(e)}
            onDragEnter={e => handleDragEnter(e)}
            onDragLeave={e => handleDragLeave(e)}
        >
            <h5>Drag json file here to upload</h5>  
        </Jumbotron>
      );
};

export default DragnDrop;
```

Then I imported it in needed component as:

```
import React from 'react';
import { Nav, Navbar, Container } from 'react-bootstrap';
import styled from 'styled-components';

import DragnDrop from '../DragAndDrop/DragnDrop';

const Styles = styled.div`    
    .navbar { 
        background-color: #fff; 
        border-bottom: 1px solid #4AA69D;
    }
    a, .navbar-nav, .navbar-light .nav-link {
        color: #000;
        &:hover { 
            color: #000; 
        }
    }
    .navbar-brand {
        font-size: 1.4em;
        color: #000;
        display: flex;
        align-items: center;
        text-transform: uppercase;
        letter-spacing: 5px;
        &:hover { 
            color: #000; 
        }
    }
    .imgPos {
        margin-right: 4%;
    }
    .profilediv {
        background: #fff;
        border-radius: 50%;
        border: 1px solid #4AA69D;
        width: 50px;
        height: 50px;
    }
    .dragdropContainer {
        margin-top: 2%;
    }
    .jumbotronSurvey {
        text-align: center;
    }
`;

const NewSurvey = props => {
    const reducer = (state, action) => {
        switch (action.type) {
            case 'SET_DROP_DEPTH':
            return { ...state, dropDepth: action.dropDepth }
            case 'SET_IN_DROP_ZONE':
            return { ...state, inDropZone: action.inDropZone };
            case 'ADD_FILE_TO_LIST':
            return { ...state, fileList: state.fileList.concat(action.files) };
            default:
            return state;
        }
    };

    const [data, dispatch] = React.useReducer(
        reducer, { dropDepth: 0, inDropZone: false, fileList: [] }
    )
    return(
        <Styles>
            <Navbar expand="lg">
                <Navbar.Brand href="/">
                <img
                    alt=""
                    src="/image.png"
                    width="30"
                    height="30"
                    className="d-inline-block align-top imgPos"
                    />{' '}
                    SurveyChamp
                </Navbar.Brand>
                <Nav className="ml-auto">
                    <div className="profilediv">
                        <span>
                            {/* ToBeAddedLater */}
                        </span>
                    </div>
                </Nav>
            </Navbar>
            <Container fluid className="dragdropContainer">
                <DragnDrop data={data} dispatch={dispatch} />
                {/* <ol className="dropped-files">
                    {data.fileList.map(f => {
                        return (
                            <li key={f.name}>{f.name}</li>
                        )
                    })}
              </ol> */}
            </Container>
        </Styles>
    );
};

export default NewSurvey;
```